# Passing value from helper thread to main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread with a try-catch block. Inside the try block I have the HTML stored in a variable which I want to load into a webview. Now Android/Java doesn't allow Webview to be called any other place apart from main thread.

How can I pass this String variable value outside the scope of thread? Making string variable final and declaring outside thread doesn't help.

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {
//UI elements
private WebView mWebView;
final Activity activity = (Activity) this.getContext();

new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                //Using thread because accessing network
                URL obj = new URL(adrequesturl);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");


                if (con.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                //*****Need this variable's value in the Main Thread
                String dataToLoad="some_custom_html";


              //mWebView is a webview that I have created and below can not get executed from inside helper thread                      
              //mWebView.loadData(dataToLoad, "text/html", "utf-8");-

                } else {
                    //Some code
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Some code
            }
        }

    }).start();


//**solution which worked for me**  
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mWebView.loadData(dataToLoad, "text/html", "utf-8");
                    }
                });


  //Now we are back to main thread

  //********Main Problem**************
  //Below mWebView.loadData is allowed but I can not get dataToLoad value here
  //mWebView.loadData(dataToLoad, "text/html", "utf-8");

}
```

Comment: Your answer is basically https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask i.e. you don't use `Thread` at all.

Comment: Just like @zapl says: You use an `AsyncTask` that runs override `doInBackground()` in a background thread and passes the results to override `onPostExecute()` on the main UI-thread. Check the link he posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a part of code in the UI Thread this way :

```
this.getContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mWebView.loadData(dataToLoad, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of how to use and what threads do when using them.
Calling

```
mythread.start()
```

starts it and its code is executed parallel.
So you cant say if

```
 String dataToLoad="some_custom_html"
```

is executed before or after

```
 mWebView.loadData(dataToLoad, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Like mithrop already said, put this somewhere after dataToLoad in the same thread

```
 this.getContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    mWebView.loadData(dataToLoad, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

});

Comment: Why should the letter U be aware of that?

Comment: writing from tablet and some autocorrect happend. Sry. Edited.